# Replicate Ionic2 style Left Side Menu in NativeScript with Angular2

Tags: ionic2, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Ionic2 gives nice template with left menu slider as per image:

[image]

[image]

Is there any NativeScript way of doing this with Angular2?

I installed `npm i nativescript-telerik-ui` in to the project and as per example http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started pleased the html code in to my file :

```
<RadSideDrawer exampleTitle toggleNavButton>
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
        <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
            <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
            <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout tkMainContent>
        <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
        <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)=openDrawer()></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

But once I run `tns run android --emulator` I can't see Deawer appeared on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have forgotten to include the `SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES` into the `declarations` of the bootstrapped `@NgModule`.

You can see full details on how to use RadSideDrawer or any of the other UI elements of the **nativescript-telerik-ui** plugin in your {N} + Angular application [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/getting-started). For specific details regarding the RadSideDrawer you can take a look at its official documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started).